# Write a program in C to create a matrix A of order m×n based on run-time integer inputs and find all elements A[i][j] such that:

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Write a program in C to create a matrix A of order m×n based on run-time integer inputs and find all elements A[i][j] such that it is smallest in the ith row and largest in the jth column.
I am new to C and I have written a code for it but it's not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int m,n,min,max;
    printf("Let the matrix be m x n\n Enter the value of m:");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Enter the value of n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int array1 [m][n];
    int min_i [m] ;
    int min_i_value [m] ;
    int max_j [n] ;
    int max_j_value [n] ;
    printf("Enter elements in the matrix");

    for (int i=0; i<m; ++i){//taking input for matrix
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j){
            scanf("%d", &array1[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<m;++i){
        array1[i][0]=min;//calculating min value in a row
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j){
            if (array1[i][j]<min){
                array1[i][j]=min;
            }
        }
        min_i_value[i]=min;//putting the min value in array
        for (int j=0;j<n;++j){
            if (array1[i][j]==min){
                min_i[i]=j;//putting the index of min value in array
            }
        }
    }
    for(int j=0;j<n;++j){
        array1[0][j] = max;
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            if (array1[i][j]>max){
                array1[i][j]=max;
                
            }
            
        }
        max_j_value [j] = max;
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            if (array1[i][j]==max){
                max_j [j] = i;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(min_i_value[i]==max_j_value[j]){
                printf("%d,(%d,%d)\n",max_j_value[j],min_i[i],max_j[j]);
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

It is returning 0(0,2) and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't correctly calculating the min and max values for rows and columns. Your assignment should be reversed.

```
        array1[i][0]=min;//calculating min value in a row
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j){
            if (array1[i][j]<min){
                array1[i][j]=min;
            }
        }
```

should be

```
        min = array1[i][0];
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j){
            if (array1[i][j]<min){
                min = array1[i][j];
            }
        }
```

and likewise for the loop that calculates the max.

Comment: I can't believe this, I lost 10 marks on my assignment today because of this, thanks a lot for your help. Also, since my question is answered, do I now delete it? I am not familiar with the regulations of this site.

Comment: No, you do not delete the question, @TusharGoyal.  You leave it alone.  You've accepted an answer (a good answer) and that's all you need to do.  In fact, I don't think you'd be allowed to delete the question now.

Comment: @TusharGoyal Welcome to what happens when you write code.  You can't see your mistakes because you thought you were correct when you wrote the code.  Your brain literally gets stuck on that pattern.  That's why others who are looking at your code for the first time can see things that are obvious to you after they show you the mistake.  I've been writing code for decades and that *still* happens to me.